# How convert image into 16bit zip (deflate) compressed TIF in python?

Tags: python, image-processing, tiff

We got 50TB of 16bit uncompressed TIF images from a industrial sensor in our server, and we want to compress them all with lossless zip compression using python. Using python because it's easier to use Python to communicate our database.

However after hours of search and documentation reading, I found that there's not even a matured python library that can convert 16bit TIF into zip compressed tif. The latest PIL cannot write compressed tif, OpenCV hardcoded output file into LZW tif not zip(deflate). And there is no sufficient documentation in smc.freeimage, PythonImageMagick so I don't know if they can do it. I also found this [tifffile.py](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/tifffile.py.html), there seems something about compression in its source code, but there is no example code that let me understand how to config compression option for output.

Of course I can use an external executable, but I just don't want to use python as scripting language here.

So that I really appreciate if anyone give me an efficient example here, thanks.

**Update:**

cgohlke's code works, here I provide another light weight solution.
Checkout the patched pythontifflib code from here https://github.com/delmic/pylibtiff.

The original PythonTiffLib from google code doesn't handle RGB information well and it didn't work on my data, this patched version works, however because the code is very old, it implies PythonTiffLib may be not maintained very well.

Use the code like this:

```
from libtiff import TIFF

tif = TIFF.open('Image.tiff', mode='r')
image = tif.read_image()

tifw = TIFF.open('testpylibtiff.tiff', mode='w')
tifw.write_image(image, compression='deflate', write_rgb=True)
```

Comment: If you can't find anything that does the job exclusively in Python and have external executable which, when passed the right argument, does the right job for you. Then I think you should make use of `sys.call` or `subprocess.call`.

Comment: @hus787, thanks, that would be my last choice.

Comment: @cgohlke,yeh, I don't think tifffile can save compressed tiff. I'm looking at the old Pylibtiff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PythonMagick works for me on Windows:

```
from PythonMagick import Image, CompressionType
im = Image('tiger-rgb-strip-contig-16.tif')
im.compressType(CompressionType.ZipCompression)
im.write("tiger-rgb-strip-contig-16-zip.tif")
```

Scikit-image includes a wrapper for the FreeImage library:

```
import skimage.io._plugins.freeimage_plugin as fi
im = fi.read('tiger-rgb-strip-contig-16.tif')
fi.write(im, 'tiger-rgb-strip-contig-16-zip.tif',
         fi.IO_FLAGS.TIFF_ADOBE_DEFLATE)
```

Or via [tifffile.py](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/tifffile.py.html), 2013.11.03 or later:

```
from tifffile import imread, imsave
im = imread('tiger-rgb-strip-contig-16.tif')
imsave("tiger-rgb-strip-contig-16-zip.tif", im, compress=6)
```

These might not preserve all other TIFF tags or properties but that wasn't specified in the question.

Comment: Thanks so much, after spending some time installing PythonMagick , it ends up working very well, I didn't test its speed, but by its dependencies, I guess PythonMagick will be very efficient.

Comment: Add the download link for PythonMagick, for linux http://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/. for windows, http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pythonmagick. Now the problem is that PythonMagick maybe troublesome to install on a cluster

Comment: Thanks, I chose the tifffile method and works perfectly (v 2020.11.18).

Comment: im trying to use  compressors for get a .tif less sized  can you share and example @cgohhkle ,like lzw